# Poisson distribution, defining lambda

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I'm currently working on the following exercise:

> The number of hits, X, per baseball game, has a Poisson distribution.
>   If the probability of a no-hit game is $\frac13$ , what is the probability of
>   having 2 or more hits in specified game?

If I understood correctly the lambda represents the average number of changes we can expect in a given time (for ie).

In this particular case, I'm thinking of  as $\lambda = \frac{(2x)}{3}$

is it correct? Is there a formula to find out such variable without much trouble or thinking? Thanks!

Comment: From the problems statement you have "If the *probability* of a no-hit game is *13*". This can't possible be right, a probability of 13 is impossible. Can you please fix this so that we know the actual question?

Comment: thank you for pointing out

Comment: No worries. If the answer written by Math1000 answered your question you may want to consider "accepting" his answer by selecting the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ then for all nonnegative integers $k$, $\mathbb P(X=k) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$. It is given that $\mathbb P(X=0)=1/3$ (it is written as $13$, but that cannot possibly be a probability, so I will read it as $1/3$), and hence
$$
\mathbb P(X=0) = 1/3 = e^{-\lambda}.
$$
Taking the logarithm of both sides yields $-\lambda = \log\frac13$ and hence $\lambda = \log 3$. It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\geqslant 2) &= 1 - (\mathbb P(X=0)+\mathbb P(X=1))\\
&= 1 - e^{-\lambda}(1 + \lambda)\\
&= 1 - e^{-\log 3}(1+\log 3)\\
&= 1 - \frac13(1+\log 3)\approx 0.3004626.
\end{align}

Comment: it's now very clear to me! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note you have two cases when lambda is equal to two or equal to three. Start from there, you have two cases I guess

Comment: Thanks for helping, do you mind elaborating a little further? I was unable to make any progress from the hint provided so far.

Comment: One case set $\lambda = \frac{2x}{3}$ and use the probability formula

Comment: Another case set $\lambda= x$. Whats k in here? That's the only thing to figure out